# How to parse a string using preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

I want to parse a string that looks something like this:

`((24x_12_)+(_42_+24))/2`

using preg_replace_callback():

```
preg_replace_callback(
     // some regex to match anything that starts with '_' and ends with '_',
    function($matches) {
        // some operation
    },
    '((24x_12_)+(_42_+24))/2'
)
```

so anything that starts and ends with `_` is replaced, in the above example above it would be `_12_` and `_42_`

more info:

1. I need the right regex: something like `/_(.+)_/`
2. The outcome would be a mathematical expression except the replaced values are calculated based on values from the DB, so `_12_` is the identifier.

Comment: Why do you think `preg_replace_callback` is needed here?

Comment: Replace with what?

Comment: You're missing some details. Like what you want to replace. What you've tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you just need help with the regex, I think you need `_.*?_`, maybe `_(.*?)_` depending on what you're going to do.

Comment: What is the expected outcome? If the question is just how to use `preg_replace_callback` that can be found here, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php.

Comment: @anubhava I want to run a calculation on the value to be replaced, i.e the matched values are used to get data and run calculations the results of which are inserted back

Comment: Use: `/_(\d+)_/` regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '|_(.*?)_|',
    function($match) {
        $number = $match[1];
        return "[There used to be a $number here.]";
    },
    '((24x_12_)+(_42_+24))/2'
); # ((24x[There used to be a 12 here.])+([There used to be a 42 here.]+24))/2
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace_callback()` would work fine to replace `_12_` with the value with ID `12` from your database, and maybe even perform 2-operand arithmetic. However it's entirely unsuitable for calculating the end result of the complex expression represented by that string. I mean, you *could* bruteforce your way through it if you're truly determined, but there are much better methods.

What you *should* do is implement an expression parser that will turn your string into a series of tokens that can *then* be interpreted by something to perform the actual calculation, eg: the [Shunting-Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it. The current requirements only need a math expression that can be `eval`'d

Comment: "If `eval()` is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question." -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP